# How to set the content mode of a VideoPlayer in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to set the content mode of a VideoPlayer in SwiftUI so it would scale to fill the desired frame?

Here's an example with an image. I wondering if it's possible to do the same thing with a VideoPlayer.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 100)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73993635/560942

Comment: The videos can be different sizes so I can't assume the ratio.

Comment: I don't think you have to assume it -- you can get it from the file.

Comment: I want to have the same frame but some videos I'm loading can have different aspect ratios. The video will only fill the whole frame if the frame has the same aspect ratio dimensions. I want to have the video fill the frame even if they aspect ratio is different like an image.